# How to judge the data in a cell is 'invalid'

Tags: matlab, cell-array

```
           ''    [  2281]    [  2520]    [8]
           ''          []          []     ''
```

Like above data in my `cell` array. How do I determine the second row is invalid? I tried `isempty()`, but the result is not optimal.

Comment: You could always just loop through the elements and check? Is this not acceptable? If not, why not?

Comment: can you provide a definition of valid? all elements in a row are empty?

Comment: `cellfun` and `all` will allow you to use `isempty`.  See my answer for details.

Comment: Just a sidenote: You may want to think about the design of your array. First of all you have two kinds of empty `[]` and `''` in the same array, secondly you have numeric data `8` and nonnumeric data `''` in the same column.

Comment: @prago Yes. All elements in a row are empty. Sorry for my late reply.

Comment: @ Dennis Jaheruddin Yea. I would like to. But so far, the part doesn't bother too much. So if there is a need, I would accept your advice.

Comment: @Chris Su,  I'm glad you now have your solution, but one suggestion -- you might consider changing the title of your question to something like, "How to determine if an entire row/column of cell array contains empty cells" to make it more general and applicable to others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `cellfun` and `all` along columns with `isempty` as follows,

```
>> invalidRow = all(cellfun(@isempty,C),2)

invalidRow =

     0
     1
```

Comment: This works well. Your solution gives me new ideas. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

here's a quick trick: combine each row in the cell array into a regular array/string (strings are char arrays), and check if it's empty. If the combined array is empty, then every element in the cell row is empty as well

```
data  = {'', [23], [45], [8];
         '', [], [], ''};
nRows = size(data, 1);
bad_r = zeros(nRows, 1);

for row = 1:nRows
    if isempty([data{row, :}])
        bad_r(row) = 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Fixed minor code mistake. Think this solution works, but still feels a bit like a hack compared to the other solution. Perhaps it can offer more memory efficiency for people dealing with very long arrays.